# Is there a way to have a size/radius legend in Bokeh?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'd like to create a scatter plot in Bokeh. Right now, I am using `bokeh.plotting.figure.circle` to create one. If I set the `radius=radvar` argument, where `radvar` is a valid string for my `source`, can I add some kind of legend so the viewer can see the scale?

Here's an example of what I'm doing now:

```
p=figure(tools=TOOLS)
p.circle(
    x=xvar,
    y=yvar,
    radius=radvar,
    radius_units='screen',
    color={
        'field':colorvar,
        'transform':color_mapper},
    source=data)
```

Seaborn has support for this kind of legend. Here's an example I found on the internet:
[image: Seaborn scale legend]

I'm not picky with howthe scale is shown. It could be just outlines, for example.

Answer (score 1):

for legend, as far as i know, no. but for glyphs, yes. `points.glyph.size` (points name refers to `points = p.scatter(...)`,) you could create size in data and create different sizes.

`